# android: how to disable all clicks on a view

Tags: android, view

I am trying to set all the properties of a view in a listview row that will react to clicks (it can be a simple press, a long click or anything else). I tried to set both parent and child views' .setFocusable, .setFocusableInTouchMode, .setLongClickable, .setClickable, .setPressed, .setSelected, .setHapticFeedbackEnabled attributes to false but it did not help.

I am switching between two states of a listview with a button click. When I switch to second state I would like to disable all the clicks on the rows. I am populating the each state of listview with different custom cursoradapters. The following code snippet is from my second cursoradapter for second state:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.title_rows_relativelayout);
    TextView lists_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_title_text);
    lists_text.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ListsDbAdapter.TITLE)));
    lists_text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_for_rows);
    parent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_for_rows);

    view.setFocusable(false);
    view.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    view.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
    view.setLongClickable(false);
    view.setClickable(false);
    view.setPressed(false);
    view.setSelected(false);

    parent.setFocusable(false);
    parent.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    parent.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
    parent.setLongClickable(false);
    parent.setClickable(false);
    parent.setPressed(false);
    parent.setSelected(false);

    lists_text.setFocusable(false);
    lists_text.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    lists_text.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);
    lists_text.setLongClickable(false);
    lists_text.setClickable(false);
    lists_text.setPressed(false);
    lists_text.setSelected(false);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post a code sample demonstrating what you've said you tried?

Comment: I just added. Sorry it takes a while to add the code because I use a different computer for programming and a different one to access internet.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem.

```
setEnabled(false)
```

..did the job for me.

Comment: Thanks, setEnabled() did the trick for me on a Listview.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you shouldn't need two adapters. You can just use one and add and onClickListener to the view that disables everything like so:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
  public void onClick(View view){
    //do all your code for disabling stuff in here
  }
});
```

Perhaps doing this and not having to switch between adapters will help you.

Comment: But when I try to change other properties of views (like background or text) it works. I cannot disable the clicks even if I set them in xml code. Do you think maybe something is wrong with my Eclipse? Because I started to think that.

Comment: BTW I use a separate button to switch between two states; it is at the bottom of the main view. It is not in the rows; I guess this was why I had to use two cursoradapters.

Comment: Ah makes sense then. Just ignore this answer then. And I doubt the problem is with eclipse.